# How to grep with a pattern that includes a " quotation mark?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, double-quotes

I want to grep a line that includes a quotation mark, more specifically I want to grep lines that include a " mark.

more specifically I want to grep lines like:

```
#include "something.h"
then pipe into sed to just return something.h
```

Comment: so you want only the text which are present inside the double quotes?

Comment: Please consider [reading the docs on how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

A single grep will do this job.

```
grep -oP '(?<=")[^"]*(?=")' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo '#include "something.h"' | grep -oP '(?<=")[^"]*(?=")'
something.h
```

Comment: The `-P` flag is not supported in all `grep`s; see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html, http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/egrep.1?query=grep. So I think this answer would be better if it mentioned some alternatives as well. (And, for that matter, if it included some explanation.)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '#n
/"/ s/.*"\([^"]*\)" *$/\1/p' YourFile
```

No need of grep (unless performance on huge file is wanted) with a sed. Sed could filter and adapt directly the content

In your case, `/"/` is certainly modified by `/#include   *"/`

in case of several string between quote

```
sed '#n
/"/ {s/"[^"]*$/"/;s/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)" */\1/gp;}' YourFile
```

Comment: But why your sed fails to extract contents between double quotes in `#include "something.h" "foo.h"` string.

Comment: depend on what is aked :-) based on the sample and the specific request about it. But you are right, i adapt the reply for more generic action

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to get included filename:

```
awk -F'"' '{print $2}' file.c
something.h
```